# String.replace()で置換した数の取得方法

Tags: java

Javaの`String.replace()`で置換した数の取得方法をインターネットやJava Docで調べているのですが、
不明です。

長文のテキストの入った`String test;`を`test.replace("あいう", "ABC");`と実行した場合、
何個置換を行ったかを取得したいのですが、何かの`String`のメンバー変数/関数で取得できないでしょうか？

もし、無理な場合、置換前に、for文で、`indexof("あいう", nowIndex + 1)`で数を数える方法などをするしかないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

置換した数をStringのメンバー変数/関数で取得することはできませんので、他の回答にある方法やfor文、[正規表現](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12414038)などを用いて置換前に数を数えるしかありません。

もし外部のライブラリを使うことが許されるならば、Apache commons-langの[StringUtils.countMatches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12414152)メソッドを使うのが手っ取り早いかと思います。

※リンク先はそれぞれstack overflow英語版の回答に寄せられたサンプルコードです。

Answer (score 0):

事前に(replace("あいう", "ABC")を実行する前に、testに”あいう"がいくつ含まれているかを調べるしかないと思います。
indexofで順に調べるよりも、探す文字列("あいう")を削除(""にreplace)したら何文字消えるかを調べ、調べる文字列の文字数で割るやり方（下記コードのような感じ）が早いです。

```
String test_work;
int orig_length;
int number_of_aiu;

test_work = test.toString(); //testのコピーを作ります。
orig_length = length(test); //testの元の文字数です。
test_work.replace("あいう",""); //"あいう"を削除した文字列を作ります。
number_of_aiu = (orig_length - length(test_work)/length("あいう"); // testに含まれている"あいう"の数です。
```

Comment: 手順はいいと思いますがコードが間違ってます。

Comment: [String.toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toString--)はStringのコピーは出来ないみたい(アドレスがコピーされる)ですので実質`String test_work=test`と同じです。`String test_work=String.valueOf(test.toCharArray())`のようにしたら正しく動きます。 もっといい方法があればそっちを使ってください

Comment: @Sun-Solar-Arrow  `replace`は元の文字列自体は変更しませんからそもそもコピーする必要はないです。（replace後の文字数が変化しないため）逆にこの場合結果を残す必要があって`test_work=test.replace("あいう","");`とする必要があると思います。あと閉じカッコ`）`が足りない。文字列の長さは`length(test)`ではなく`test.length()`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  そうですね、ご指摘ありがとうございます

Answer (score 0):

> 何かのStringのメンバー変数/関数で取得できないでしょうか？

無理だと思います。

> 無理な場合、置換前に、for文で、indexof("あいう", nowIndex + 1) で数を数える方法などをするしかないでしょうか？

`String#replace(...)`は、以下のような実装になっているので、

```
public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) {
  return Pattern.compile(target.toString(), Pattern.LITERAL)
                .matcher(this)
                .replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement.toString()));
}
```

- [Matcher (Java Platform SE 8 )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

  - > 新しい文字列の内容は、必要に応じてマッチ結果から算出できます。appendReplacementおよびappendTailメソッドを同時に使用すれば、結果を収集して既存の文字列バッファに格納できます。
- [Methods of the Matcher Class (The Java™ Tutorials > Essential Classes > Regular Expressions)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html)

などを参考に、置換回数を数えるのが効率は良さそうです。

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class RegexDemo {
  private static final String REGEX = "dog";
  private static final String INPUT = "dog dog dog doggie dogg";
  private static final String REPLACE = Matcher.quoteReplacement("ABC");
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX, Pattern.LITERAL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT);
    int count = 0;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
      count++;
      m.appendReplacement(sb, REPLACE);
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println("count: " + count);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    //System.out.println(m.replaceAll(REPLACE));
  }
}
```

Comment: 皆様ご回答ありがとうございます。indexofは、遅い為、NG。文字列を""へ置換し文字数をカウントする方法は、採用OK。「置換回数を数えるのが効率は良さそうです。」は、ソースまで頂きましたので、採用OK。従いまして、最後の効率が良さそうという方法を採用させていただきます（効率が良い方法が望ましいと判断しましたので）。皆様、色々アイデアやコメントをありがとうございました。大変たすかりました。

Comment: 質問に対して十分な回答が得られた場合、それを承認済みとマークしておくと、後で閲覧する人の参考になります。
[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか?](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)などを参考に、
質問のクローズをしてもらえると助かります。

Comment: 追記: もっと効率良く変換したい場合は、`StringBuffer`ではなく`StringBuilder`を使用したいところですが、
今のJVMならロック除去最適化などで、`StringBuffer`でもそこそこ速くなっているらしいので、手間を考えるとこのままでいいかなと...。
参考:[Java 6のスレッド最適化は実際に動作しているのか？](https://www.infoq.com/jp/articles/java-threading-optimizations-p1)

Answer (score 0):

[split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-)を使って
置換回数:`test.split("あいう", -1).length-1`
とするのがお手軽かもしれません。

※splitの最初の引数は正規表現文字列なので、正規表現に当たる文字などはエスケープする必要があります。